# Dynamically creating a table

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a table dynamically using JavaScript. So far i'm trying to understand what am i doing wrong. At first i'm making a table element and then i set id for that element. After that i'm looping through rows and as i do that, i create new columns in each new row. The problem which i'm having is that it stops making only 1st row. Can someone point out mistake im making?

```
var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
x.setAttribute("id", "newTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);
for (i=1;i<5;i++){
    var y = document.createElement("TR");
    y.setAttribute("id", "newTr");
    document.getElementById("newTable").appendChild(y);
       for (j=1;i<10;i++){
           var z = document.createElement("TD");
           var t = document.createTextNode("cell");
           z.appendChild(t);
           document.getElementById("newTr").appendChild(z);
       }
}
```

Comment: id's should be unique

Comment: every time you do document.getElementById("newTr").appendChild(z); it will get you the first row, since all rows have the same id

Comment: Thank you both for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = document.createElement("TABLE");
x.setAttribute("id", "newTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);

for (i=1;i<5;i++){
  var y = document.createElement("TR");
  y.setAttribute("id", "newTr"+i);
  document.getElementById("newTable").appendChild(y);
  for (j=1;j<10;j++){
    var z = document.createElement("TD");
    var t = document.createTextNode("cell");
    z.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("newTr" +i).appendChild(z);
  }
}
```

i changed your second for-loop from `i` to `j` and i made the td-element id unique.

Comment: I took a different approach to making unique id's but as far as this question goes, this is one of the approaches which someone could take. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that you mixed up `j`and `i`

```
 for (j=1;i<10;i++){
       var z = document.createElement("TD");
       var t = document.createTextNode("cell");
       z.appendChild(t);
       document.getElementById("newTr").appendChild(z);
   }
```

try

```
for (i=1;i<10;i++){  //j here changed to i;
       var z = document.createElement("TD");
       var t = document.createTextNode("cell");
       z.appendChild(t);
       document.getElementById("newTr").appendChild(z);
   }
```

Comment: Didn't even see that. Thank you!